# QML object change from c++ class for Gomoku game

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I am trying to make a Gomoku game using qml and c++. I have created a 10 * 10 board using qml grid and repeater. like this....

```
Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    color: "#241d2b"
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Grid {
        x: 10; y: 10
        width: 418
        height: 418
        property bool defineColor: true
        rows: 10; columns: 10; spacing: 2

        Repeater { 
            model: 100
            Rectangle { 
                width: 40; height: 40
                color: "white"

                MouseArea{
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    TapHandler{
                        id:tapped
                        onTapped: ghuti.visible = uiBridge.showLog(index)
                    }
                }
                Rectangle {
                    id: ghuti
                    visible: false
                    radius: width*0.5
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    anchors.rightMargin: 5
                    anchors.leftMargin: 5
                    anchors.bottomMargin: 5
                    anchors.topMargin: 5
                    //anchors.fill: parent
                    color: "red"
                }
                Rectangle {
                    id: ghuti2
                    visible: false
                    radius: width*0.5
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    property string property0: "none.none"
                    anchors.rightMargin: 5
                    anchors.leftMargin: 5
                    anchors.bottomMargin: 5
                    anchors.topMargin: 5
                    //anchors.fill: parent
                    color: "black"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The human input can be easily captured by mouse click...but in reply, computer need to turn. But I do not find and clue for automatic computer turn in right place. The two rectangles inside the loop ...one is for human input and other is for computer input.`

Comment: *"But I do not find and clue for automatic computer turn in right place."* What exactly are you looking for here? Are you wanting a way to simulate a mouse click for the computer player?

Comment: after user turn computer should automatically turn

Comment: That's not specific enough. Are you wanting us to write your AI for you?

Comment: I have made a code for ai.....my game is running well in the console..Now I want to integrate qml ui . But I can input user turn by mouse click...in response computer should turn another ...

but I can not make computer tern in ui

Comment: But what does a "computer turn" mean? Are you just wanting to call some function after a timeout? You have not defined what you want. I'm voting to close this question unless you can describe an actual programming question.